# PHP: Check does email contains "@" and "."

Tags: php, if-statement

Im new in php and this should be a easy to make, but I dont now how. 
I want to check does $address has characters "@" and "."

```
<?php 
    function testEmail($address){
        $a = strpos("/@/", $address);
        $b = strpos("/./", $address);
        if (($a != false) && ($b != false)) {
            echo "Email is OK";
        } else {
            echo "Email is NOT OK";
        }
    }
    testEmail("testmail@gmail.com");
?>
```

Comment: You're confusing strpos() with preg_match()... you don't need the / pattern delimiter for strpos

Comment: @ Mark Baker I try preg_match(), but even if dont put period in string, it says that string is fine

Comment: @CodeCaster that was copy/paste mistake, but still not working, as result give me Email is NOT OK

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use filter_var to check validity of email.

```
$email = 'gaurang@gmail.com'
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
// Email correct
}
else {
//Email not correct
}
```

Comment: its not about checking email, its about simple check does string contain these two characters ("@", "."), it doesn't have to be email at all

Answer (score 2):

Is your question about this specific piece of code? Then @wroniasty's answer is correct. 
But you really don't want to use a regex to test email validity, unless you want to use monstrosities like [these](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

However, if your question really is *"How can I validate an email address?"*, then take a look at [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

You can pass it the filter [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), so it will validate the email address catching quite a bit of edge cases.

You can check an address using the following code:

```
if (filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // valid email
} else {
    // invalid email
}
```

Comment: its not about checking email, its about simple check does string contain these two characters ("@", "."), it doesn't have to be email at all

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function testEmail($address) {
    if (preg_match ( "/\.|@/", $address)) 
       echo "Email OK";
    else
       echo "Email not OK";
}
?>

a better way to check for valid email address:

<?
function isValidEmail($email){
return preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste that from 10 years ago?

Comment: That `eregi` looks like from another time ^^

Comment: I see. Actually it was 6 years ago.

Comment: @user1709910 there was a `)` missing.